# Install4j build on windows renders code signing error CSSMERR_TP_NOT_TRUSTED on OSX

Tags: macos, certificate, code-signing, install4j

I am using Install4j Multi-Platform 5.1.3 on Windows XP and I am attempting to code-sign my bundle for Mac OSX (Mountain Lion).  I have installed Apple's intermediate certificates on both Windows XP and mac.  I have followed directions on obtaining certificates through Xcode organizer and keychain. I have attempted to use certificates for both installer and application.

After I build I move the .dmg file to the mac and open it.  I copy the .app file to another location in order to execute:

codesign -vvv -d myapp.app

It reports the message:
myapp.app: CSSMERR_TP_NOT_TRUSTED

Comment: Forgot to mention that my certificate's trust is set to "Use System Defaults."

Answer (score 1):

I'm getting closer to a solution.  It turns out that where install4j5 is installed there is a resource\macos\certs.  This folder contains the Apple root certificate and Developer ID certificate.  I deleted those and updated them from http://www.apple.com/certificateauthority/.

After my build CSSMERR_TP_NOT_TRUSTED is no longer being reported.  Instead, it is the certificate info.

Now when I install with safari (using Gatekeeper) it is reporting "can't be opened because it is from an unidentified developer."  Before with CSSMERR_TP_NOT_TRUSTED, gatekeeper was reporting that the file was damaged.

Comment: From the first paragraph in my answer:  I believe when you add to the folder that you have to restart install4j5 to take effect.

Comment: It's now working.  I forgot to copy my developer id certificate to that folder.  In addition, I double-clicked on all certificates and followed instructions to install them on system.  Restarted install4j and now the result of my builds are working.

Comment: I think you're still using the wrong certificate for code signing. What you've probably done is just installed the wrong certificate as trustworthy on your system. If you use the right certificate you don't have to update or install any certificates.

Comment: ej-technologies confirmed that my install and certificates were valid.